# How are transactions ordered in POS?

Tags: transactions, mining, proof-of-stake, proof-of-work

With POW, the miners who finds the block chooses the order of transactions in that block. How will this work with POS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POW and POS are both methods of choosing the miner who will have the privilege of appending a block to the canonical chain.

POS doesn't change the idea of ordering transactions in ordered blocks. It changes the method of selecting a miner.

Hope it helps.

Comment: From my understanding, to be a "miner", you stake your x ETH. Do each of these "miners" now have the opportunity to choose the tx order?

Comment: Any if all "miners" are equal, how does the software choose the miner?

Comment: In both cases, the miner has that privilege over one block at a time. In POW, it has to solve a puzzle to win the privilege. In POS they acquire that privilege in proportion to their stake. Implementation details may vary. As a general model, think of a "miner" who has staked 5% of all funds staked by all miners. They might get the privilege every 20 blocks - 5% of the time.